# Call windows forms control method inside wpf's WindowsFormsHost

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, windowsformshost

I have created my own WindowsFormsControl. This control has a public method LoadDocument:

```
public partial class SignNowFormsControl : UserControl
{
    public SignNowFormsControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void LoadDocument(string PathToDocument)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Dokument " + PathToDocument + " wird geladen.");
    }
}
```

Now, I embed this control in wpf's xaml:

```
<WindowsFormsHost x:Name="SignNowFormsHost" Margin="0,0,0,0">
    <signNowFormsControl:SignNowFormsControl x:Name="SignNowFormsControlItem" x:FieldModifier="public" />
</WindowsFormsHost>
```

In code behind I try now to call the LoadDocument method of the control:

```
public void LoadDocument(string PathToDocument)
{
    this.SignNowFormsControlItem.LoadDocument(PathToDocument);
}
```

Now, when I build the project I get the following error:

> 'SignNowFormsControl.SignNowFormsControl' does not contain a
>   definition for 'LoadDocument' and no extension method 'LoadDocument'
>   accepting a first argument of type
>   'adeon.SignNowFormsControl.SignNowFormsControl' could be found (are
>   you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Can someone please explain me what is wrong here? Is it not possible to use methods with parameters here? Do I have to write the values to properties instead?

Comment: maybe you need this: `this.SignNowFormsControlItem.Child.LoadDocument` ?

Comment: Is `SignNowFormsControl` deriving from WPF UserControl class or WinForms UserControl class?

Comment: SignNowFormsControl is deriving from System.Windows.Forms.UserControl

Comment: It should work then. Have you make sure all dependencies are build properly?

Comment: I believe so. Strange behaviour is also that intellisense and resharper don't show any error. But build does not work.

Comment: There has to be something in your code then because i tried this and its working fine at my end. Try `Clean/Build` or `Rebuild` of complete solution.

Comment: It was indeed some kind of missconfiguration. I also recreated the references between the projects and it finally built.

Answer (score 0):

The code above does actually work. After cleaning and rebuilding the whole solution there was no build error any more.